# Kendo UI Chart - OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, kendo-ui

I'm using kendo ui charts, and need to trigger onclick event when you click on individual bars of a chart/graph.

I can not seem to find a way to trigger the onlcik event using jq.

Here is a fiddle,

does anyone know how achieve this?

```
<script>
       $("#WastOfTime").click(function(){
             alert("Ignore this, could not post a Fiddle without code");
       });
 </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/louisila/S6d7M/

Answer (score 1):

You could add

```
$("body").on("click", "path", function(e) {
    if($(this).data("model-id")) {
        alert("Here we go");
    }
});
```

at the end of your JS.

Edit: added condition to exclude clicks outside the bars.

Example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s39Ka/).

Comment: This causes alerts when clicking outside of the bars too.

Answer (score 1):

This is out of the Kendo UI Documentation. Not sure what a "note" is considered, but they have a few click events.

`$("#chart").kendoChart({
  series: [{
    data: [{ value: 1, noteText: "a" }]
  }],
  noteClick: function(e) {
    console.log(e.text);
  }
});`

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart#events

Answer (score 0):

```
This ended up being the solution.
```

Thanks anyways!

```
.bind("seriesClick", function (e) {

                console.log("worked");
            })
```